# Pass a variable number of args to python script

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

My script has to accept a variable number of arguments, more exactly between 1 and 3 args and I need to use `argparse` module to achieve this. I have the following approach in which I verify the length of `args.keys` list:

```py
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=" Process input as json array and return a nested dictionary ")


parser.add_argument('keys', nargs='*', type=str, help="keys used to contruct dict object")
args = parser.parse_args()

if len(args.keys) < 1 or len(args.keys)>3:
    print("Min 1 arg \nMax 3 args")
else:
    print("keys: {} ".format(args.keys))
```

But I do not feel this is a good approach, are there any other ways to verify/limit the no of arguments passed to the script ? Thx.

Comment: Add a condition when you get the Argos back to see if it fits your limit?

Comment: What's wrong with this?  `argparse` does not implement a range form of `nargs`.  Some time ago I wrote a patch that would accept a `re` style of range, but I don't think that will ever be added.  Doing your own test after parsing is the logical way to do it.

Comment: Agree with hpaulj with one note: you can change the `*` to `+` and at least get rid of the `<1` check (`+` checks for at least one argument)